# Bringing a picture to the front in an image stack, by use of an anchor element, through user

Tags: css, image, z-index

For an interactive application I have four pictures stacked behind each other. The user shall decide, which one to view, by clicking on the respective anchor and bringing it to the front. (I cant use an iframe, as I work in impress.js and it interferes with the fade in)

I have a [simple code example](http://codepen.io/TheRed/pen/byGDA) with three divs:
Any solutions with z-index, css, js are welcome.

HTML

```
 <a href="blue">bring blue to front</a>
 <a href="green">bring green to front</a>
 <a href="red">bring red to front</a>

 <div id="blue"></div>
 <div id="green"></div>
 <div id="red"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0;
 }

 #blue {
background: blue;
z-index: 1;
}
#green {
background: green;
}
#blue {
background: red;
}
```

Comment: You do know that you have a typo: you have written the #blue selector twice. Presumeably you mean #red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be also done with `:target` pseudo class: http://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/hFDre

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in pure css, but it requires some changes to your html:

[updated CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eAsGr)

### html

```
<label for="blue">bring blue to front</label>
<label for="green">bring green to front</label>
<label for="red">bring red to front</label>


<input type="radio" id="blue" name="rads">
<div id="blue"></div>
<input type="radio" id="green" name="rads">
<div id="green"></div>
<input type="radio" id="red" name="rads">
<div id="red"></div>
```

### css

```
div {width: 200px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 100px; z-index:0;}
label { cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; border-right:1px solid red; padding:0 10px;}
input[type="radio"] { display:none;}
input[type="radio"]:checked + div {z-index:10;}
#blue{background: blue;}
#green {background: green;}
#red {background: red;}
```